# How to retrieve only files while search in box net

Tags: box-api

For pagination we have option to set limit and offset in request object, but it retrieves all files along with folders that match search string. Our requirement is to get only matching files skipping folders with the given limit. Skipping folders is effecting pagination.

The below commented line by default dont' allow to mention specific type:

```
boxSearch = boxNetContext.getBoxClient().getSearchManager().search(searchFileName, boxDefaultRequestObject);
```

We made this below change such that we pass type as `FILES`.

```
SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest(boxNetContext.getBoxClient().getConfig(), boxNetContext.getBoxClient().getJSONParser(), searchFileName, boxDefaultRequestObject);
boxSearch = (BoxCollection) boxNetContext.getBoxClient().getSearchManager().getResponseAndParseAndTryCast(request, BoxResourceType.FILES, boxNetContext.getBoxClient().getJSONParser());
```

This change is not working. It also retrieves both files and folders.
Kindly help us to retrieve only matching files with out effecting pagination

Answer (score 0):

The [Search API documentation](http://developers.box.com/docs/#search-searching-a-users-account) doesn't provide a way to filter by `type`. It does, however, state that:

`as you’re parsing the results, be prepared to skip over any types of items your app does not recognize.`

So it seems that you'll need to filter these results in your code. If you need to display a set number of results per page, you may need to perform multiple search queries in order to cache the required number results.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion from my experience on Android platform.

find the file of com.box.boxjavalibv2.requests.SearchRequest.java, change the code as below

```
public SearchRequest(final IBoxConfig config, final IBoxJSONParser parser, final String searchQuery, BoxDefaultRequestObject requestObject)
        throws BoxRestException {
        super(config, parser, URI, RestMethod.GET, requestObject);
        addQueryParam("query", searchQuery);
}
```

To

```
public SearchRequest(final IBoxConfig config, final IBoxJSONParser parser, final String searchQuery, BoxDefaultRequestObject requestObject)
    throws BoxRestException {
    super(config, parser, URI, RestMethod.GET, requestObject);
    addQueryParam("query", searchQuery);
    addQueryParam("type", "file");
}
```

Then the result are pure files without folder.

Good Luck.